# jQuery delete current row previously added

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

How can I delete a row from a table which it has been created with a delete button before?

I need to add an event to btnDeleteOther to delete the current row selected.
I would also need to know how to change id for each textbox created, and populate the value of the textbox with the variable coming to the function(but I guess I would have to ask that in other question).

Code example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function createNewRow (text1,text2){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append('<tr><td>
    <input type="text" id="title1" value=""/>
           </td><td>
       <input type="text" id="title2"/>
       </td><td>
       <input type="button" id="btnDeleteOther" value="X"/>
       </td></tr>');
    });
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="float:left" id="tblOtherParties">
  <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>Title1</th>
     <th>Title2</th>
     <th>
      <input type="button" id="btnAddOther" title="Add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:createNewRow();"/>
     </th>
    </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>
        <input type="text" id="title1"/>
           </td>
           <td>
        <input type="text" id="title2"/>
           </td>
           <td>
        <input type="button" id="btnDeleteOther" value="X"/>
           </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, I am having a hard time understanding what you need to do.

Do you need to delete the tr associated with the delete button when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes sorry I think I did it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your Delete buttons should have a class, not an ID.

Comment: You also have issues with id="title.... those ID's will be duplicated as well.

Comment: Thank you all, I dont know how to accept as solution as most of answers are right.

Comment: @Cesar - just pick the "right" answer that you have tested, that is best for you - you can also upvote other answers if they also work to give some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues beyond just getting your row deleted.

This:

```
   function createNewRow (text1,text2){ 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append('<tr><td> 
    <input type="text" id="title1" value=""/> 
           </td><td> 
       <input type="text" id="title2"/> 
       </td><td> 
       <input type="button" id="btnDeleteOther" value="X"/> 
       </td></tr>'); 
    }); 
     }
```

would be better written as:

```
function createNewRow (text1,text2){ 
    $('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append('<tr><td> 
    <input type="text" class="title1" value=""/> 
           </td><td> 
       <input type="text" class="title2"/> 
       </td><td> 
       <input type="button" class="btnDeleteOther" value="X"/> 
       </td></tr>'); 
     };
```

and as for the

```
  <input type="button" id="btnAddOther" title="Add" value="Add" onclick="javascript:createNewRow();"/>
```

clean that up with

```
  <input type="button" id="btnAddOther" title="Add" value="Add" >
```

Then use the jQuery to act the behavior you wish

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnDeleteOther').live('click', function() {  
        if ($('.btnDeleteOther').length > 1)
        {
           $(this).closest('tr').remove();               
        }; //added this based on comments to other answer- always leaves one row in
    }); 
    $('#btnAddOther').click(function()
    { 
       createNewRow();
    });
});
```

EDIT:  HUGE assumption on my part is you might want to pass text to the inputs when you add a row as you have the (text1,text2) in there...

To do that, you need a source of those, then you can do that with this:

```
var mytext1 = "default stuff for 1";
var mytext2 = "default stuff for 2";

function createNewRow (){ 
        $('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append('<tr><td> 
        <input type="text" class="title1" value=""/> 
               </td><td> 
           <input type="text" class="title2"/> 
           </td><td> 
           <input type="button" class="btnDeleteOther" value="X"/> 
           </td></tr>'); 
           $('tr:last').find('.title1').val(mytext1);
           $('tr:last').find('.title2').val(mytext2);
        };
```

Comment: @Mark Schutheiss: Thanks for all the effort you are putting on helpping me out. I think your advise it really good, but for some reason I get a Unterminated string constant error when using your code.
PS:I did fix the issue with delete button, its now a class. Thanks. :-)

Comment: NOTE: this is not "perfect" but I tried to keep it as close to yours as possible yet solve the issues.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can have multiple Delete buttons, they should be identified by a classname, not an ID.  (eg, `<input type="button" class="DeleteButton" value="X"/>`)

You can then write the following:

```
$('.DeleteButton').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**EDIT**: To prevent it the last row from being deleted, you can write

```
    $(this).closest('tr').not(':only-child').remove();
```

---

To populate the textboxes, you could write the following:  (Note that these also need classnames instead of IDs)

```
var newRow = $('<tr>...</tr>');
newRow.find('.Title1').val(title1);
newRow.find('.Title2').val(title2);
newRow.appendTo($('#tblOtherParties > tbody'));
```

Comment: @Slaks: thank you very much for the advise, I did not about the delete button id. :-)

Comment: $(this).closest('tr:not(:only-child)').remove(); Will remove the whole table. :-(. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#btnDeleteOther").live("click", function(){
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks! That its perfect, just one last thing, could you tell me how to stop this function from deleting when there is only one row left?

Comment: Check `$(this).closest("tr").siblings().length` to see how many other table rows exist.

Comment: Sorry I tried $(this).closest("tr").siblings().length, but I dont think I am using it right as it does not do anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Assumption is you fixed the #btnDeleteOther to be a class so $('.btnDeleteOther').length should give you a count of rows with a delete button.  See my answer for an example of use.

Comment: @Cesar, you would need to put that within the click-logic, as part of an if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the delete button either a unique id per row or a class rather than assigning it a fixed id.  Element ids in HTML must be unique.  I would suggest giving it a class, then applying the live class-based selector as @Jonathan suggests.  As @Mark points out, the same applies to your textboxes.  In my sample I've changed it to use names instead of ids, but perhaps they need to be unique as well.  Adjust as needed to fit your situation.

```
$(function() {
   $('.deleteButton').live( 'click', function() {
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
});
function createNewRow (text1,text2){ 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append('<tr><td>' +
       + ' <input type="text" name="title1" value=""/>'
       + '</td><td>'
       + '<input type="text" name="title2"/>'
       + '</td><td>'
       + '<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="X"/>'
       + '</td></tr>'); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Not going to work with the id="title1" and id="title2" stuff in there.

Comment: @Mark - I guess I was too focused on the delete button, but yes the inputs need to be unique (or use names instead) as well. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

For older jQuery you can do

```
$("#btnDeleteOther").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

Also to change the textbox's id you can do the following when injecting

```
var content = $("<CONTENT>");
content.find("#title2").attr("id", "title" + something);
$('#tblOtherParties > tbody').append(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are appending an item with id="btnDeleteOther" . So, it seems that you could be have  more than one item with the same id. You should give the appended one(s) a unique id [keep a count / append a timestamp / etc].

Attach a click event to the button and then  call remove on the tr. using something like:
$(this).closest('tr').hide();

Also, since you will be adding new items, then you probablly want to look into .live() so that new items will get the click event.